# Is there any way to close a window/tab in firefox with javascript? (window.close is not helping with mozilla)

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I am trying to close a window after taking a prompt in plain javascript, and it is working properly in all but mozilla(current version 31.0). Please suggest any tricks to solve it. I also tried first opening the tab, and then closing it. It did not work.

Comment: I just tested `window.close()` in the console of a Mozilla browser. It definitely works. What does your code look like?

Comment: `<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function closeIt()
  {
   window.close();
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <p onclick="closeIt()">close tab</p>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: I think It is not supposed to close the windows it doesn't own. See [link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183697) here, it says the fact that it used to be able to do it before was a bug, not the current one. Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to trick the browser into closing the window in FireFox

```
<a href="javascript:closeWindow();">Close Window</a>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function closeWindow() { 
        window.open('','_parent',''); 
        window.close(); 
    } 
</script>
```

[Source](http://www.yournewdesigner.com/css-experiments/javascript-window-close-firefox.html)

Comment: No, that did not work either. As I have mentioned in the question, I have already tried opening it and closing it,since it says only the tabs opened by script can be closed by script. That does not help.

Comment: I think It is not supposed to close the windows it doesn't own. See [link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183697) here, it says the fact that it used to be able to do it before was a bug, not the current one. Thanks anyway